# Replacing multiple characters in a string with regex (looking for improvement)

Tags: jquery

So this actually works but I feel like it could have something removed, but I cant figure out what. I need to wrap certain letters in  tags, in this example k, r and s:

```
var characters = new RegExp('(k|r|s)', 'gi');
$('.header h1').html(function() {
    $(this).html($(this).html().replace(characters, "<span>$1</span>"));
});
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simplify by using the arguments returned to `html(function)` which are the index and current html

```js
const reg = /(k|r|s)/gi;

$('.header h1').html(function(i, curr) {
    return curr.replace(reg, "<span>$1</span>");
});
```

```css
.header h1 span { color: red}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="header">
   <h1>Christmas Cookies</h1>
</div>
```